# How do I target the Django setting module in an environmental variable on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I want to run my stand-alone script `csvImp.py`, which interacts with the database used by my Django site BilliClub. I'm running the script from the project root (`~/BilliClub`) on my virtual environment `django2`.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/) but for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` rather than the secret key. The part that trips me up is what value to assign to the environmental variable. Every iteration I've tried has yielded an error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BilliClub'` after running
`(django2) 04:02 ~/BilliClub $ python ./pigs/csvImp.py`.

I am reloading the shell every time I try to change the variable in `.env` so the `postactivate` script runs each time and I'm making sure to re-enter my virtualenv. The problem just seems to be my inability to figure out how to path to the settings module.

The `.env` file:

```
# /home/username/BilliClub/.env #

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="[what goes here???]"
```

Full path of my `settings.py` is `/home/username/BilliClub/BilliClub/settings.py`.

Abridged results from running `tree`:

```
(django2) 04:33 ~ $ tree
.
├── BilliClub
│   ├── BilliClub
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── pigs
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── bc2019.csv
│   │   ├── csvImp.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── ...
```

Comment: could you share csvImp.py sample with imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should make `csvImp` a custom management command and then
`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is `"BilliClub.settings"` When you write your utility function as Django Management Command you get all the Django configuration for free, and the root directory of your command is the same as the root directory of the web app, and its the directory where `manage.py` is.

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Great, this works and is a much more elegant solution than what I had. Helps for other functionality I was planning as well.